# How do i get the records which is having the maximum records in sql table

Tags: php, mysql

I am having the user table which is having the field call 'City'. Now i want to get all the users which is having the maximum city belongs from. I want to fetch for 5 cities which are having maximum users.

For example :
Delhi is having 100 users, Mumbai is having 350 users, banglore is having 100 users, pune is having 50 users, Ahmedabad is having 20 users, Kolkata is having 20 users, chennai is having 30 users, Rajkot is having 25 users something like this...

Now i want to get the city who is having maximum users. In this case, i want to get Delhi, Mumbai, banglore, Pune, Chennai and Rajkot.

I am using mySql as a query language.

Please help me in this...

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: You should have a look at the `GROUP BY` clause in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MySQL `group by city` or `count(city)` or `ORDER BY` like that :-

```
select count(city) as user_count from user group by city 
ORDER BY count(city) DESC limit 5
```

Comment: also add the limit  "limit 5" after city